# Matlab: Saving multiple Dicom files as jpeg or png format

Tags: matlab, image-processing, save, png, dicom

I can read a Dicom format file and display it using `imshow()`. Then, manualy I can save the file into jpeg or png using `saveas` option. This works for one file at a time. However, I have around 1000 such dicom files. How can I save multiple dicom data files as jpeg format into another folder?

This is how I read one file at a time:

```
 X = dicomread('C:\Users\skm\Desktop\DicomRaw\578A0BF9');
imshow(X);
%Then from the figure I go to saveas option to save the file as jpeg.
```

This is what I have tried for multiple files

```
%read multiple images

FileList = dir('C:\Users\skm\Desktop\DicomRaw\*.*');
Converted_jpeg = dir('C:\Users\skm\Desktop\Jpeg_file\*.*');

N = size(FileList,1);

for k = 1:N

   % get the file name:
   filename = FileList(k).name
   disp(filename);

end
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code sample:

```
indir = 'C:\Users\skm\Desktop\DicomRaw\';  %Input folder name with DICOM files.
outdir = 'C:\Users\skm\Desktop\Jpeg_file\'; %Output folder name for storing jpg files.
FileList = dir([indir, '*.*']); %Get list of all files in input folder.

for k = 1:N
    % get the file name:
    filename = FileList(k).name;

    %Verify there is no dot in file name (in case folder contains other files).
    if (~any(filename == '.'))
        X = dicomread([indir, filename]);

        %Add .jpg extension to file name
        out_filename = [filename, '.', 'jpg'];

        %Use imwrite for saving (better than using imshow and saveas).
        imwrite(X, [outdir, out_filename]);
    end
end
```

Comment: The code runs but there is no output. I tried to debug using `disp(filename);` but there is no output for this statement as well. The problem maybe due to the line `FileList = dir('C:\Users\skm\Desktop\DicomRaq\*.dicom');` but the original files don't have any extension as such. I have attached a screenshot of the folder containing the files of dicom format.
`

Comment: In your post you wrote: `FileList = dir('C:\Users\skm\Desktop\DicomRaw\*.*');`. Why did you change it to `dir('C:\Users\skm\Desktop\DicomRaq\*.dicom');`? I edited my post, and also added a check that input file name has no `.`